# Compare and remove array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

i have a bug in this code that i cannot seem to solve.  if there is only 1 instance of Act, it works as it should. But when there is more than 1 instance of Act, it breaks. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
//Find all instances of italics
var findItalics = new RegExp(/(<em>.*?<\/em>)/g);
var italicsArray = [];
var italicCount;

while (italicCount = findItalics.exec(searchInput)) {
    italicsArray.push(italicCount[0]);
}

//Find the italics containing the word 'Act'
var keywordItalics = new RegExp(/<em>.*?(Act).*?<\/em>/g);
var keywordItalicArray = [];
var italicCountKeyword;

while (italicCountKeyword = keywordItalics.exec(italicsArray)) {
    keywordItalicArray.push(italicCountKeyword[0]);
}

//Remove all instances of the keyword(s)
for (var tlcs = italicsArray.length - 1; tlcs >= 0; tlcs--) {
    if(italicsArray[tlcs] == keywordItalicArray) {
        italicsArray.splice(tlcs, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you comparing an element and an array? `italicsArray[tlcs] == keywordItalicArray`?

Comment: I've created two arrays. basically i am looking for a match. if it matches, i want it removed from the array.

Comment: Do you want this ?`keywordItalicArray.indexOf( italicsArray[tlcs] ) != -1`?

Comment: I believe so. I dont even think I need the keywordItalicArray . I should be able to find the RegExp from the italicsArray no?

Comment: Please make working fiddle, then can help you to solve.

Comment: Basically I need this

if (italicsArray contains this new RegExp(/<em>.*?(Act).*?<\/em>/g)) {
remove it from the array
}

Comment: Thanks @artgb that fiddle helped me solve it. I was missing a loop inside of the final loop.

Comment: Happy to hear that you got answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @artgb who helped me rethink this.

```
//Find all instances of italics
var findItalics = new RegExp(/(<em>.*?<\/em>)/g);
var italicsArray = [];
var italicCount;

while (italicCount = findItalics.exec(searchInput)) {
    italicsArray.push(italicCount[0]);
}

//Find the italics containing the word 'Act'
var keywordItalics = new RegExp(/<em>.*?(Act).*?<\/em>/g);
var keywordItalicArray = [];
var italicCountKeyword;

while (italicCountKeyword = keywordItalics.exec(searchInput)) {
    keywordItalicArray.push(italicCountKeyword[0]);
}

//Remove all instances of the keyword(s)
for(var xXx = 0; xXx < keywordItalicArray.length; xXx++){   
    for (var tlcs = italicsArray.length - 1; tlcs >= 0; tlcs--) {
        if(italicsArray[tlcs] == keywordItalicArray[xXx]) {
            italicsArray.splice(tlcs, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var keywordItalics = new RegExp(/<em>.*?(Act).*?<\/em>/g);
```

Should usually be shortened to:

```
var keywordItalics = /<em>.*?(Act).*?<\/em>/g;
```

Where your () are, this would only get a capture of "Act", so to capture whole string in the em, it should be:

```
var keywordItalics = /<em>(.*?Act.*?)<\/em>/g;
```

However, a faster way (without regexp) you could get an array of all the emphasized tags just by:

```
var keywordItalics = document.getElementsByTagName('em');
```

If you're just trying to get rid of all em's containing "Act", all you should need is:

```
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
     /<em>.*?Act.*?<\/em>/g,
     ''
   );
```

This should remove all traces of em's containing "Act" in the document (effectively replacing those strings with an empty string, aka nothing).  It will cause a reflow, however.  If they are inside a containing element besides body, would be better to get containing element first (instead of using body).  There are "better" ways of doing this, but this is probably simplest coding-wise.

Update:  an easy way to remove em's with "Act" from the array would be:

```
italicsArray = italicsArray
  .join('_SEP_')  // Convert to string
  .replace(/<em>.*?Act.*?<\/em>/g,'')  // Delete matched entries
  .replace(/(_SEP_)+/g,'_SEP_')  // Collapse multiple seperators 
  .split('_SEP_')  // Convert back to array 
;
```

This basically uses a seperator `_SEP_` (to avoid collisions with strings containing ',') and turns the array into a string, deletes all matches to your regexp, removes what would become undefined entries, and recreates the array in the same name.

Comment: Thanks. But I need this removed from the array. Not the body. :)